# Sort Most Popular based on Day/Week in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I'm developing a website somewhat similar to hulu, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to display the most popular content for that day as well as the most popular for the week based on hits... The only way I can think of doing this would be to log each and every hit in mysql along with a timestamp but that doesn't seem like the best way of doing it.. does anyone know of a better solution?

Comment: How many visitors/traffic do you expect? If it will be little, you can (in my opinion) go for logging pageviews into a database. If you have to take care about caching and stuff I am not really sure what to do. MAYBE you could try parsing your log files in an interval of an hour or so (cronjob maybe?) and update your "most popular" on a hourly basis.

Comment: If you have a table where you track it all in, its an easy job. If you work with a session, you can track sessions and stamp the time. Every session has a different ID, making it pretty easy to sort them out. Just count them and sort them by date, and you ll have your users per day.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't Google Analytics do the job ?

Answer (score 0):

If you still do the MySQL, you can run this query with some modifications once an hour:

```
INSERT INTO most_popular (day, week, content_id, created) 
    SELECT DAYOFYEAR(visited), WEEKOFYEAR(visited), content_id, NOW() 
    FROM visit_log WHERE visited > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

and then do with most_popular table what you want. the main idea is background processing.